# found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - spriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a problem with my touch event function, it says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
I am trying to click on a node which is under a label.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    let location: CGPoint = touches.anyObject().locationInNode(self)
    let nodes: NSArray = nodesAtPoint(location)

       for node: AnyObject in nodes {
           println("node name : " + node.name) // Error here
       }
```

Error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Console output:

```
node name : myLabel
node name : MyNode
```

The problem appears only on my device, it worked perfectly on the simulator.
Xcode 6.4, SDK 8.0, target 7.0, Device 7.1.2

**EDITED:**

Code of my only sprite in the scene. Got the unwrapped error when I click on it.

```
   var score: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode()
    score.text = "0"
    score.name = "scoreLabel"
    score.fontName = "Chalkduster"
    score.fontSize = 42
    score.zPosition = 100
    score.fontColor = UIColor.redColor()
    score.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) - 50, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - 40)
    self.addChild(score)
```

Comment: What does `nodesAtPoint()` look like? It seems to be different from the instance method in the `SKNode` class.

Comment: Did you set the name property for all nodes in your scene?

Comment: @CraigOtis I think that may be a subclass of `SKNode`, meaning he is calling `nodesAtPoint` on `self`

Comment: All my nodes have a name, The function is located in my class: "class PlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate"

Comment: Try setting a break point on the println and see which node is causing the crash

Comment: So There is en empty node (<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> '<data>' (200 x 74)] position:{-50, -3} size:{100, 37} rotation:0.00). But I didn't create an empty node...

Comment: The texture and size should tell you what it is.

Comment: I have only a few sprite and no one match with this size, also I don't know what is <data> texture. The fact is it works pretty good on simulator and don't have a problem with this ghost sprite, only on my device it bugged

Comment: Try replacing the node.name in the println with "node" and enumerate over all nodes with self.children (or Swift equivalent) instead of nodes to see how many "ghost" nodes are in your scene.

Comment: Still got the same ghost, with same output code as over

Comment: Do you still have that ghost node if you don't add any sprites to your scene?

Comment: No ghost without any sprites. I put only 1 sprite in my scene and got the unwrapped error when I click on it. Look the edited code in the question of my only sprite in the scene.

Comment: I implemented the same in Objective-C and only the SKLabelNode is in my scene.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to Try It Device :

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    let location: CGPoint = touches.anyObject().locationInNode(self)
    let nodes: NSArray = nodesAtPoint(location)

       for node: AnyObject in nodes {
           let strName = node.name as string
           println("node name : \(strName)") 
       }
```